# Should I say "Happy new year 'to whole' / for whole Clinton family"?

Tags: prepositions

What is correct?

> 1. Happy new year **to whole** Clinton family.
> 2. Happy new year **for whole** Clinton family".

Answer (score 5):

I'd probably use

> Happy **N**ew **Y**ear **to** ***the*** **entire** Clinton family!

Comment: And if they did use *whole*, they'd still need to add *the*.

Comment: This family is made of a lot of families. Do you understand it from the statement "To the entire family"? (I'm not an English native speaker. Sorry)

Comment: Like some here say, "me neither".  But I don't exactly get your question here.  Care to rephrase?

Comment: @Dory - When you say, "This family is made of a lot of families," I think you are referring to an [_extended family_](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+extended+family). But I wouldn't use that term in a Happy New Year greeting. If you are wishing all the Clintons a Happy New Year, then use "whole" or "entire". If you are one of the Clintons, change the preposition: _Happy New Year **from** the entire Clinton family_.

Comment: I might also consider phrasing it "HNY to *the clan*!" I would only do it when relaying the wish via a close friend. This would cover their in-laws (not all necessarily named Clinton) as well. *The extended family* is a safer alternative (and does include the in-laws). *The clan* would be intended as mildly facetious (coming from me at least). May be the (extended) family recently added another branch, and I would seek to congratulate them about that at the same time :-)

Answer (score 1):

If Joe Clinton can tell that, or assumes that, your greeting is being sent to other Clinton family members in other locations, "to the whole Clinton family" is grammatically correct and correctly implies the "extended" Clinton family (= family of families).